# Laravel - what is the best and most efficient way of displaying, sorting and filtering an array of data? (not database)

Tags: laravel, sorting

I make an external API request which returns a JSON list of items. Note, no database is used.

Now I need to display this data on screen, and allow the user to change the order (by name, by ID), paginate and filter out results.

I can do this a classic way using javascript perhaps, but is there a good fluid data sorting/filtering/displaying mechanism?

I thought maybe Vue might come in useful here (I'm not experienced with it, but I'm guessing it's more efficient than using vanialla JS)?

Any ideas or suggestions on best practices, and cleanest most efficient methods?

Comment: vue js doesnt ship with sorting functions. JS got `sort` `filter` and the like.

Comment: that's good to know, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Laravel [collections](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#introduction) provide a fluent mechanism for working with datasets.  The [`sortBy`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-sortby) method gives a good example of working with structured data.

```php
$collection = collect([
    ['name' => 'Desk', 'price' => 200],
    ['name' => 'Chair', 'price' => 100],
    ['name' => 'Bookcase', 'price' => 150],
]);

$sorted = $collection->sortBy('price');

$sorted->values()->all();

/*
    [
        ['name' => 'Chair', 'price' => 100],
        ['name' => 'Bookcase', 'price' => 150],
        ['name' => 'Desk', 'price' => 200],
    ]
*/
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks good. But I think I'm leaning towards filtering and sorting the results without having to reload the page.

Comment: Ah, you tagged it with `[laravel]` so I assumed you were making the API call from within PHP.

Comment: I am, and while your suggestion would be a good solution, it involves reloading the page every time we change the ordering/filter. I thought of perhaps using Ajax to call the data post-body render, but as the API requests are only accepted from the server IP, not the user IP I would have to ajax a request back to the server  which will then request the info fom the API, and I think this will be too slow.

Comment: Just set up an API route to proxy requests to the external API and do any transformation you need on the server (e.g. `array_only` perhaps if you need to hide certain data). You can also cache the external API response (or pre-load at regular intervals) to avoid calling it all the time if you expect this route to get busy.  If you have other data to fuse into the external API response, then I would do the sorting/filtering wherever that data exists.

Comment: Additionally there are some pretty good display frameworks out there specifically for Laravel - check out Inertia.js or Livewire.

Comment: Thanks, Inertia.js looks interesting!